# Возврат объекта типа T

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Имеется такой код:

```
public static FrameworkElement GetParentOfType<T>(FrameworkElement element)
{
    if (element is T) return element;
    while (true)
    {
        element = element.Parent as FrameworkElement;
        if (element is T) break;
    }
    return element;
}
...
MyPanel myPanel = (MyPanel)GetParentOfType<MyPanel>(myTextBox);
MyLabel myLabel = (MyLabel)GetParentOfType<MyLabel>(myTextBox);
...
```

Но мне хотелось бы сделать что то вроде этого:

```
public static T GetParentOfType<T>(FrameworkElement element)
{
    if (element is T) return element as T;
    while (true)
    {
        element = element.Parent as FrameworkElement;
        if (element is T) break;
    }
    return element as T;
}
...
MyPanel myPanel = GetParentOfType<MyPanel>(myTextBox);
MyLabel myLabel = GetParentOfType<MyLabel>(myTextBox);
...
```

Но как хотелось бы не работает. Где об этом почитать или как быть? Сам искать пытался, но как правильно сформулировать запрос не знаю.

Comment: Как именно не работает, исключение или не компилируется?

Comment: Код вроде бы правильный, объясните, в чём проблема.

(Я бы всё же написал `while (element != null)`: <http://ideone.com/wwUNaj>.)

Comment: второй пример не компилируется. По поводу корректности выхода из цикла написано на самом деле по другому. Просто код сократил для выявления интересующей проблемы. Попробуйте сами, не компилируется.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Надо вот как:

```
public static T GetParentOfType<T>(FrameworkElement element)
                                                     where T : FrameworkElement
{
    if (element is T) return element as T;
    while (element != null)
    {
        element = element.Parent as FrameworkElement;
        if (element is T) break;
    }
    return element as T;
}
```

Comment: а смысл тогда использовать дженерики? если выходной тип ограничивается конкретным классом, проще тогда его и указать как тип выходного параметра.

Comment: @Carma: `where T : FrameworkElement` означает, что `T` -- производный от `FrameworkElement` класс, как раз то, что и требуется в вопросе.

Comment: это я понял, мне не совсем ясно тогда, чем это будет отличаться от public static FrameworkElement  GetParentOfType(FrameworkElement element) и далее по тексту использовать FrameworkElement. Например, если сам FrameworkElement  является производным от T

Comment: Если `FrameworkElement` является производным от `T` (а не наоборот), код не скомпилируется. Отличие от вашего примера -- в типе возвращаемого значения: поскольку мы уверены в том, что тип будет не просто `FrameworkElement`, а даже `T`, вы можем сделать downcast, чтобы этого не пришлось делать пользователям нашего метода.

Comment: а смысл тогда от дженерика? Почему не использовать сразу public static FrameworkElement GetParentOfType(FrameworkElement element, если предпологается, что Т это производный от FrameworkElement, и в противном случае код не скомпилируется.

Comment: Ну, во-первых, надо как-то передать искомый тип. Во-вторых, этономим каст: в вашем случае надо `Button b = (Button)GetParentOfType(...)`, в моём `Button b = GetParentOfType(...)`

Comment: В обоих случаях будет вызов будет Button b = GetParentOfType<Button>(...). Но в Вашем случае применяется ограничение типа, и будет работать для производных типов, но не для базовых.

Comment: @Carma: не совсем, в вашем случае `Button b = GetParentOfType<Button>(...)` не скомпилируется. Потому что FrameworkElement -- менее специфический тип. Попробуйте сами, это ж легко проверить.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Работает!

Comment: @krupennikov: пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй что-то такое

```
public T ConvertTo<T>(SomeType val)
{
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(val, Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(T)));
}
```

Т.е. использовать принудительное преобразование типа, а не оператор as

Comment: Че-то такое будет работать с шаблонами C++, но не с дотнетовскими дженериками, поскольку во время компиляции отсутствует какая-либо информация о типе T.

Comment: Исправил. Спасибо.